# How to find the inversion of f(x)=(6x mod 13)?

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Finding the inversion of an easier function is simple. The way I find the way of doing this by flipping the x and the y in the equation and solving for y. But I am stuck on a certain part.

y = (6*x) mod 13

x = (6*y) mod 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the inverse of `y = 6 * x mod 13`, I am first going to solve for `x` and replace x with y (and vice versa) later.

Since `y = 6 * x mod 13`, `x = 6^(-1) * y mod 13`, where `6^(-1)` is the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of `6` for the modulus `13`. Your task now becomes finding `6^(-1) mod 13`. In other words, you have to find `m` such that `6 * m = 1 mod 13`.

Note that `6 * 2 = 12 = -1 mod 13`. Squaring both sides, `6 * 6 * 2 * 2 = 1 mod 13`, or `6 * 24 = 1 mod 13`. Since `24 = 11 mod 13`, therefore `6 * 11 = 1 mod 13` and `11 = 6^(-1) mod 13`.

Thus, our equation for `x` now becomes `x = 11 * y mod 13`. Replacing `y -> x` and `x -> y`, the inverse of the given function is given by `y = 11 * x mod 13`.

This nifty Python script can be used to test the validity of our result:

```
def f(x):
    return (6 * x) % 13

def f_inv(x):
    return (11 * x) % 13

for x in range(13):
    print x, f_inv(f(x)), x == f_inv(f(x))
```

When run, it gives the following output:

```
0 0 True
1 1 True
2 2 True
3 3 True
4 4 True
5 5 True
6 6 True
7 7 True
8 8 True
9 9 True
10 10 True
11 11 True
12 12 True
```

Thus validating the premise that `f^(-1)(x) = 11 * x mod 13` satisfies the required premise that `f^(-1)(f(x)) = x`.

Comment: Similarly for another question I'm trying your methods and found it is impossible to find the inversion of f(x) = 6x mod 15. Why is this?

Comment: Because `6^(-1) mod 15` does not exist. For `a^(-1) mod m` to exist, `gcd(a, m) = 1`, but `gcd(6, 15) = 3 != 1`.

Comment: But of course that only means there are no integer solutions. One possible inversion for `y = 6x mod 15` would be `y = x/6 `. Another solution is `y = (x + 15)/6` and so on. But if you put in an integer between 0 and 14 for x, the result will never be an integer.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of that function will only be defined for values between 0 and 12. Also for every possible y (in between 0 and 12) there will be an infinite number of possible x that fulfill the equation.

Let's try to solve for y

```
x = (6*y) mod 13
x + n*13 = (6*y)
y = (x + n*13)/6 | x ∈ {0,…,12}, n ∈ ℕ
```

where n is an unknown positive integer that could have any arbitrary value

Comment: If we are in the domain of (0,12) then what would the inverse function be. Are you saying that it is impossible to find the inverse of a modular function?

Comment: It's possible to find the inverse, but it will give you many solutions.